# Oracle concurrent programming execution methods

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I created a package and stored procedure under it to test a concurrent program.when I run it as an Oracle report executable method. It works fine. But I change it to PL/SQL stored procedure then it gives error.

> Cause: FDPSTP failed due to ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306:
>   wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'pop_rpt_tbl' ORA-06550:
>   line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

It's working properly in a oracle report method.

Any idea about this issue.

```
This is my sp  
PROCEDURE pop_rpt_tbl (
      p_pro_id   IN       NUMBER,
      p_agr     IN        NUMBER,
      p_prd       IN       NUMBER,
      p_group_id     IN     NUMBER,
      x_api_status   OUT      VARCHAR2,
      x_api_msg      OUT      VARCHAR2
   );
```

When I execute this as a PL/SQL I gave package name.pop_rpt_tbl as a file name and the executable as a package name.

Comment: you should post the relevant pieces of code...

Answer (score 2):

When you create a packaged procedure to be run as a Concurrent Request, you should define the Executable as PL/SQL and specify the `schema.package.procedure` as the Executable File Name.

Next, the first two arguments of your packaged procedure **must** be `errbuf OUT VARCHAR2,    retcode OUT NUMBER`. The concurrent process expects this; your own arguments should come after these first two. So a prototype packaged procedure specification would similar to:

```
  PROCEDURE create_manual_batch (
    errbuf OUT VARCHAR2,
    retcode OUT NUMBER,
    p_part_id IN VARCHAR2,
    p_quote_line_id IN VARCHAR2,
    p_parent_id IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '0');
```

You may use `errbuf` and `recode` in your code to send back useful information to the application. You can pass an error message string to `errbuf` which will write to the log file, and you can set the retcode in your program to show success or failure or error in the EBS Concurrent Request form:

- 0 = Normal
- 1 = Warning
- 2 = Error

Comment: Thanks for your reply i did what ever you mentioned here.. changed the executable name and the procudure..first i got error like insuffcient priviledge to execute. then i grant permition.still i'm having this issue.

Comment: @user361045 You don't have to change your executable name, I was just giving an example. In your case you executable file name is 'pop_rpt_tbl'. In what schema did you create your procedure? APPS? Or another schema? If you did not create your procedure in APPS, then you will need to 'GRANT EXECUTE ON pop_rpt_tbl TO APPS'. You should then also specify the schema name when you list your executable file name as 'myschema.pop_rpt_tbl'.